# knockout loads, but does not work in IE

Tags: internet-explorer, knockout.js

I'm building a client-side application with jquery and knockoutjs. It works great in FF and Chrome, but crashes in a really puzzling way in IE v8.

For debugging, I'm running this code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  //A bunch of code that works fine ...
  //...
  alert( viewModel );
  alert( ko.toJSON );
  alert( ko.toJSON(viewModel) );
  ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
  alert( "Done" );
});
```

IE gives me two alert boxes:

```
[object Object]
```

and

```
function(a){a=p.oa(a);return p.a.Y(a)}
```

The first one is my viewModel. I believe the second is the minimized ko.toJSON command. Why can't it run the third alert? This happens even if I set viewModel to something simple, like {};

(BTW, the ko.applybindings line doesn't work either. That's why I was debugging in the first place.)

Comment: version 8.0.6001.  But I'd like for this to work across all recent versions

Comment: try running in debug mode, F12, check the console for any exceptions

Comment: Good suggestion. Here's the error message: "Cannot find JSON.stringify(). Some browsers (e.g., IE < 8) don't support it natively, but you can overcome this by adding a script reference to json2.js, downloadable from http://www.json.org/json2.js" This solves the alert problem, but not the original problem with ko.applyBindings.  In that case I get an uninformative "'_destroy' is null or not an object" from a line deep within knockout-1.2.1.js

Comment: sounds like either your viewModel or your markup have something wrong, if you can post a full example or set up http://jsfiddle.net/ we can be of better help

Comment: I appreciate the help.  I'm out of time tonight (East Coast), but I'll post something first thing tomorrow morning.

Comment: Any luck with this? You may want to also update to the latest version of Knockout.

Comment: Thanks for the follow up.  I got sidetracked, but will be working on cross-browser issues for this app next week.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are running in IE 8 Compatibility Mode or in IE 7 Mode. Hit F12 and check your browser mode.

Answer (score 0):

I know some versions of IE don't support JSON natively and so it has to be included as a JavaScript include. Crockford's JSON2 parser: https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js

But the compatibility mode of IE, if set correctly should also resolve this.